# Make `busctl` only output `data` (i.e. don't include `type`)

Tags: dbus

- The context
- The question
- Additional information

## The context

I know that `busctl` can be used to get the number of pages of the current document in a Zathura instance.

```sh
busctl --user get-property org.pwmt.zathura.PID-17525 /org/pwmt/zathura org.pwmt.zathura pagenumber
```

```
u 187
```

As you can see above, the output includes `u` which indicates the `type` of the value being returned. The fact that `u` is `type` can be proved by using `--json=pretty`.

```sh
busctl --json=pretty --user get-property org.pwmt.zathura.PID-17525 /org/pwmt/zathura org.pwmt.zathura pagenumber
```

```
{
    "type" : "u",
    "data" : 187
}
```

I don't need to know the `type` of the value returned, I just want to get `data`. I know it is possible to use some external tools to get rid of the `type`. For example:

```sh
busctl --user get-property org.pwmt.zathura.PID-17525 /org/pwmt/zathura org.pwmt.zathura pagenumber | cut -d ' ' -f 2
```

```
187
```

```sh
busctl --json=short --user get-property org.pwmt.zathura.PID-17525 /org/pwmt/zathura org.pwmt.zathura pagenumber | jq -r '.data'
```

```
187
```

## The question

In order to reduce the computational complexity of the programs I write and avoid doing repetitive tasks, I've considered this as a principle: instead of extracting data of the output of a program, the program should output the data in the desired format. So, my question is: How to make `busctl` output `data` without including `type`?

## Additional information

You might be thinking that's not big deal. However, for more complex `data`, hiding the `type` becomes more difficult:

```sh
busctl --user get-property org.pwmt.zathura.PID-17525 /org/pwmt/zathura org.pwmt.zathura documentinfo
```

```
s "{\n  \"filename\" : \"/home/rdrg/my/calibre/Unknown/Unknown (348)/Unknown - Unknown.pdf\",\n  \"number-of-pages\" : 187,\n  \"index\" : []\n}"
```

The following gets rid of `type`, but the string is escaped, and now I need to process all the string to unescape it.

```sh
busctl --user get-property org.pwmt.zathura.PID-17525 /org/pwmt/zathura org.pwmt.zathura documentinfo | cut -d ' ' -f 2-
```

```
"{\n  \"filename\" : \"/home/rdrg/my/calibre/Unknown/Unknown (348)/Unknown - Unknown.pdf\",\n  \"number-of-pages\" : 187,\n  \"index\" : []\n}"
```

The following gets ride of `type`, but we needed to use a `jq` which is a parser and might require a significant amount of computional complexity.

```sh
busctl --json=short --user get-property org.pwmt.zathura.PID-17525 /org/pwmt/zathura org.pwmt.zathura documentinfo | jq -r '.data'
```

```
{
  "filename" : "/home/rdrg/my/calibre/Unknown/Unknown (348)/Unknown - Unknown.pdf",
  "number-of-pages" : 187,
  "index" : []
}
```

Comment: In your last example…the string value is JSON, so wouldn't you need `jq` to parse it *anyway*? (Although it's bit weird that zathura returns stringified JSON instead of a native D-Bus dict...)

Answer (score 0):

> How to make busctl output data without including type?

You don't. It outputs the message type unconditionally and doesn't have any hidden options to skip that part of its code.

```c
                } else {

                        fputs(sd_bus_message_get_signature(reply, true), stdout);
                        fputc(' ', stdout);

                        r = format_cmdline(reply, stdout, false);
                        if (r < 0)
                                return bus_log_parse_error(r);

                        fputc('\n', stdout);
                }
```

> In order to reduce the computational complexity of the programs I write and avoid doing repetitive tasks, I've considered this as a principle: instead of extracting data of the output of a program, the program should output the data in the desired format.

Following from that, instead of wrangling a generic tool to output the format you want, a specific tool should be written that directly performs the desired task.

As well, if you are *already* writing a program, you should be using D-Bus directly within that program instead of calling `busctl` or other shell tools.

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import argparse
import dbus
# import json

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("pid")
args = parser.parse_args()

bus = dbus.SessionBus()
obj = bus.get_object("org.pwmt.zathura.PID-%s" % args.pid,
                     "/org/pwmt/zathura")
obj_prop = dbus.Interface(obj, "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties")

res = obj_prop.Get("org.pwmt.zathura", "pagenumber")
print(res)

# res = obj_prop.Get("org.pwmt.zathura", "documentinfo")
# res = json.loads(res)
# print(res["number-of-pages"])
```